# find specific words in a string then push to array

Tags: php, regex

Consider :

```
$array=array();
$string = "an url link: url('example.com/abc'),another url link :url('example1.com/foo=bar')";

if (preg_match("regex expression of url('')")
    array_push("the whole url string start from 'url(' then end with ')'");
```

Suppose I have the code above , how to write the above statement in the correct way ?

Comment: 1) Since you want all matches and not just one match you want to use `preg_match_all()` 2) Use https://regex101.com to put your input data into it and play a bit with the regex field. Start simple by just matching the word `url` and then build up the regex to your goal. Also use the reference at the bottom right corner of that site.

Comment: alright,how can i get the string that matches the regex and push them in the array ?

Comment: If you use `preg_match_all()` you can look into the manual and will see that the 3rd parameter will hold your results and in this array (see the structure with: `print_r($yourMatches);`) will be your results which you can add to your array.

Comment: @Rizier123 , this function is really a savior , but in the output array , there are 2 unecessary element "('example.com/abc')" , how can i remove it ?

Comment: Note that the first SubArray will hold all full matches and then the second one will hold the first capturing group, then second and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fE0

```
preg_match_all("/url\(\'(.*?)\'\)/", $inputSTR, $output);
```

`preg_match_all` will match all parts of the string that meet the criteria.

`\( and\'` means escape regex and make it literal. In short, make sure the ( is a ( and not a part of the regex pattern.

`(.*?)` match anything and be lazy. This means to only match till first time the regex is no longer matched.

`\'\)` the end of the search pattern

Comment: Why do you use `preg_match_all()` here? What does `.*?` mean? I don't think everyone knows this, so it might be helpful to explain that a bit what exactly you do here, even though it might look simple to you or me.

Comment: your answer is great ,but in my array there's unecessary element like this:'example.com/abc' , how can i get rid of them ?

Comment: @Rizier123 , he use preg_match_all() to get all string that match the regex

Comment: Have you looked at the link? I have taken care of the ' in the string